# What is the source for this quote by Maimonides?

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam

I have often heard a quote attributed to Maimonides which goes:

> “Hear the truth, whoever said it.”

What is the source for this quote?

Comment: https://www.orharambam.com/post/%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%95

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5458/13438 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/118119/13438

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is from the Rambam's [introduction to the Eight Chapters](https://www.sefaria.org/Eight_Chapters%2C_Introduction?vhe=The_Eight_Chapters_of_Maimonides_on_Ethics,_by_Joseph_I_Gorfinkle&lang=bi)

> Know, however, that the ideas presented in these chapters and in the
> following commentary are not of my own invention; neither did I think
> out the explanations contained therein, but I have gleaned them from
> the words of the wise occurring in the Midrashim, in the Talmud, and
> in other of their works, as well as from the words of the
> philosophers, ancient and recent, and also from the works of various
> authors, as **one should accept the truth from whatever source it
> proceeds** (ושמע האמת ממי שאמרו).

Answer (score -2):

See the introduction to the Guide of the Perplexed, where Maimonides states that the truth is the truth no matter what its source.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct source